# Mongodb complex updating of all documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."), 
    "cityName" : "New York", 
    "factories" : [
        {
            "factoryName": "factory1",
            "productAmount": 400,
            "numberOfWorkers": 5,
            "workersProductionPerSecond": 0.1
        },
        {
            "factoryName": "factory2",
            "productAmount": 200,
            "numberOfWorkers": 3,
            "workersProductionPerSecond": 0.2
        }
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."), 
    "cityName" : "New Jersey", 
    "factories" : [
        {
            "factoryName": "New factory",
            "productAmount": 100,
            "numberOfWorkers": 5,
            "workersProductionPerSecond": 0.25
        },
        {
            "factoryName": "New Factory 2",
            "productAmount": 200,
            "numberOfWorkers": 5,
            "workersProductionPerSecond": 0.4
        }
    ]
}
```

And lets say I want to have a service that updates **every second** the `productAmount` of all the factories ( imagine there are hundreds of cities with hundreds of factories in each one ).
The updating of the `productAmount` needs to be like this pseudo code

productAmount += numberOfWorkers **( of this factory )** * workersProductionPerSecond **(of this factory)**;

May anyone please suggest a good efficient mongodb query / a good javascript code to update the product amount of all the factories of all the cities? Or maybe in order to make a simple query that does it the factories should be in their own collection with a foreign key for the cities?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a simple `$map`:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      factories: {
        $map: {
          input: "$factories",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            factoryName: "$$item.factoryName",
             productAmount: {$add: [{
              $multiply: [
                "$$item.numberOfWorkers",
                "$$item.workersProductionPerSecond"
              ]
            }, "$$item.productAmount"]},
            numberOfWorkers: "$$item.numberOfWorkers",
            workersProductionPerSecond: "$$item.workersProductionPerSecond"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZnA7WaAjyjO)

Nevertheless, if each factory is a document with a foreign key for the city, the equivalent query will be even simpler.